# Adjusting varying thickness of bar in seaborn barplots for subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

In a seaborn horizontal barplot, which has two set of barplots where one set is placed on top of another, how the axes of each can be controlled independanlty? Currently, I want to adjust the thickness of the bars based on the frequency of the occurrence of some entity in it.

Currently both the barplots are plotted with axes stored in `ax1` and `ax2`. But I am able to adjust the thickness of the bar only for `ax1` (lightblue in colour), but not for `ax2` (dark blue. All bars have uniform thickness). I am not able to figure out how the assignment of `ax2` needs to be done so as to adjust the bar thickness for the second set of bars as well.

How can varying length bars for both the barplots be obtained?
[image: Sample Plot]

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")


f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 45))
crashes = plotie.groupby('target_wcount').mean()

sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
ax1 = sns.barplot(x="uno", y="indie", orient='h',  data=crashes,
            label="uno", color="b")
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
ax2 = sns.barplot(x="miss", y="indie", orient='h',  data=crashes,
            label="miss", color="b")


for bar, newwidth in zip(ax1.patches, summa):
    bar.set_height(3*newwidth)

for bar, newwidth in zip(ax2.patches, summa):
    bar.set_height(3*newwidth)

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
f.savefig('filea')
```

#### Sample For data

```
    output_wcount   missing_count   match_count     uni     indie   uno     miss
target_wcount                           
49  49.0    39.440000   9.560000    1.0     49  1.0     0.804898
48  48.0    36.730000   11.270000   1.0     48  1.0     0.765208
46  46.0    34.400000   11.600000   1.0     46  1.0     0.747826
45  45.0    33.940000   11.060000   1.0     45  1.0     0.754222
44  44.0    34.630000   9.370000    1.0     44  1.0     0.787045
43  43.0    31.420000   11.580000   1.0     43  1.0     0.730698
42  42.0    31.455000   10.545000   1.0     42  1.0     0.748929
41  41.0    29.630000   11.370000   1.0     41  1.0     0.722683
40  40.0    28.430000   11.570000   1.0     40  1.0     0.710750
39  39.0    27.935556   11.064444   1.0     39  1.0     0.716296
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `twinx` function this could be easily solved

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 45))
crashes = plotie.groupby('target_wcount').mean() 
sns.set_color_codes("pastel")
ax1 = sns.barplot(x="uno", y="indie", orient='h',  data=crashes,
            label="uno", color="b")
sns.set_color_codes("muted")


ax2 = ax.twinx()


sns.barplot(x="miss", y="indie", orient='h',  data=crashes,
            label="miss", color="b",ax=ax2)


for bar, newwidth in zip(ax1.patches, summa):
    bar.set_height(3*newwidth)

for bar, newwidth in zip(ax2.patches, summa):
    bar.set_height(3*newwidth)

sns.despine(left=True, bottom=True)
f.savefig('filea')
```